# Get actual DateTime of a device in Offline Mode

Tags: android, datetime, offline

I am developing an android application.  I need to solve the below mentioned issue in my application:

1) The application can work in online as well as offline.  The app has a feature to create and save the NOTES inside the application.  Also, When the app gets internet connection, I need to send the NOTES to backend server.  I have a field called 'DATECREATED' in each NOTE (the datetime where the actual NOTE was created)

**ISSUE:**
If the User has set the DateTime wrongly in the device, My application sends the incorrect DATETIME to server.  I am wondering how could I solve the issue?
Any Ideas would be appreciable.

Comment: can you post your code here..

Comment: Sorry, It is not related to code.  I need a logic to implement the usecase

Comment: What's the problem sending a datetime that reflects whatever the user has on his/her device?

Comment: The created time is important for future reference. It is client requirement.

Answer (score 4):

When you eventually post to your server, just add that specific time as well. `new Date().getTime()` will give you a value that you can use to compare with the datetime of your server. If it's for example 2 hours later, then just set the time of the post 2 hours back.

So send both the time when the post was submitted by the user and the time when it was actually sent.

Comment: Thanks.  There could create problems If the user changes the time of the device after creating the NOTE.  Any other solutions to solve this usecase?

Comment: I can't seem to find a callback or some sort of listener that notifies about device settings. You could however run a Service that checks every couple of seconds (lets say 30) if the time is the same as oldTime + 30 and continue from there, but this might become quite an overkill

Comment: Yes.  I feel the same.  I don't think that any other solutions available.

Comment: @AneesDeen maybe at the moment of creating note start timer for that note. and then, when you have internet connection, post note with time passed from creating.

Comment: The Notes are indefinite..If I start timer for each note, It is really a overhead.  Also, What happens If I kill the app and open again?

Answer (score 0):

You can get current date and time by using network time.

```
LocationManager locManager = (LocationManager) mContext
            .getSystemService(mContext.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    long lastSyncTime = locManager.getLastKnownLocation(
            LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER).getTime();
```

I have used it to get time, based on location in my application.
I think it will work in online and offline mode as well.

Comment: What happens if its a tablet with only wifi?

Comment: As per last location when you connected with internet, its show the time.
You need this permission as well:

android.Manifest.permission#ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION

Comment: This is just the time when you've received your last location update. Internally it gets the time on exactly the same way as you would with 'new Date().getTime()' or 'System.currentTimeInMillis()'. So if a user changed the date settings of the device, it will still be wrong